# Trying to display multiple inputs on a single line in an R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have an R Shiny app that I'm building with several input options. I want three of the numericInput options to appear on one line with each taking up about a third of the space. I've looked for several answers but can't seem to find a simple one. Below is the UI portion of the Shiny app - any thoughts on how to get them on the same line?

```
if(interactive()){

    ## load required packages
    library(shiny)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px; position:relative;",
                p(strong("1. Select draft settings")),
                numericInput(inputId = "pass_td_pts",
                             label = "Pass TDs",
                             value = 4,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 8,
                             step = 0.5,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "pass_yd_pts",
                             label = "Passing Yards",
                             value = 0.04,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 1,
                             step = 0.01,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "int_pts",
                             label = "Interceptions",
                             value = -2,
                             min = -5,
                             max = 5,
                             step = 1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "rush_td_pts",
                             label = "Rushing TDs",
                             value = 6,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 10,
                             step = 1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "rush_yd_pts",
                             label = "Rushing Yards",
                             value = 0.1,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 1,
                             step = 0.1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "fum_pts",
                             label = "Fumbles Lost",
                             value = -2,
                             min = -5,
                             max = 5,
                             step = 1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "rec_td_pts",
                             label = "Receiving TDs",
                             value = 6,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 10,
                             step = 1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "rec_yd_pts",
                             label = "Receiving Yards",
                             value = 0.1,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 1,
                             step = 0.1,
                             width = '33%'),
                numericInput(inputId = "rec_pts",
                             label = "Recptions",
                             value = 0.5,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 2,
                             step = 0.05,
                             width = '33%'),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("draftPlot")
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fluidRow](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) will work.

For example, put the first three numericInput in the same line:

```
if(interactive()){

    ## load required packages
    library(shiny)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px; position:relative;",
                p(strong("1. Select draft settings")),
                fluidRow(
                    column(4, numericInput(inputId = "pass_td_pts",
                             label = "Pass TDs",
                             value = 4,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 8,
                             step = 0.5,
                             width = '33%')),
                    column(4, numericInput(inputId = "pass_yd_pts",
                             label = "Passing Yards",
                             value = 0.04,
                             min = 0,
                             max = 1,
                             step = 0.01,
                             width = '33%')),
                    column(4, numericInput(inputId = "int_pts",
                             label = "Interceptions",
                             value = -2,
                             min = -5,
                             max = 5,
                             step = 1,
                             width = '33%'))),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("draftPlot")
            )
        )
    )
```

Then you can have another two fluidrow() for the rest input.